# Jasmine test for event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I
have a backbone view and in the initialize function I have an event listener:

```
this.$el.on('hide', this.hideModal.bind(this));
```

So Im binding the current context to the callback.

I want to write a jasmine test (im using v2.0.0) for this but initializing the view means I get the error:

```
 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.hideModal.bind(this)')
```

If I was to remove the `.bind(this)` and use `var self = this` as a global variable within the view, it will work. But that means I have to make my code more messy just so that it can be testable. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sounds like you're using PhantomJS? If that's the case, have a look at https://github.com/tschaub/karma-phantomjs-shim. You're probably running a version with an old javascript implementation that does not support `Function.bind`.

Comment: yes thats correct. Im now using _.bind() instead